# Force driver installation in spite of undue ERROR_NON_WINDOWS_NT_DRIVER

Tags: installation, driver, windows-8, device-driver

Installation of a device Driver on Windows 8 Fails with the following error:

```
0xe000022d -536870355 ERROR_NON_WINDOWS_NT_DRIVER
```

The decimal number was what I found in the error log (`C:\Intel\Logs\IntelGFX.log`), and a web search turned up the error Symbol Name.

As I downloaded the Driver [straight from Intel (Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator Driver for Windows* XP)](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldId=12536), I do believe that it is an NT Driver. Just not for Win7 or Win8, but for XP and possibly adapted for Vista.

The device in question doesn't do Aero, but I don't Need Aero, so turned it off. I would, however, love to have the native Resolution and Hardware acceleration. Which is why I would love this Installation to succeed.

My assumption is that the Driver Installation Routine (the Intel Driver Setup program) interacts with the operating System in some ways in order to determine how exactly to install the Driver, and by way of prudence it barfs at the first sights of Errors; so that in theory a user who deems he knows better should be able to force the Installation. (It's only a preview System with no real data or functionality at the Moment, so why not Play around a Little.)

- (1) Any idea what this error really means?
- (2) Any way to Bypass the regular Driver Installation? Sort of force-install the Driver?
- (3) Pointers like "What every programmer Needs to know about device Drivers" are also welcome, as a fallback to #1 and #2.

I found this error code [documented in the SetupAPI on the `DIF_ALLOW_INSTALL` request page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543663.aspx), but I know next to nothing about this API.

---

Okay, Ken's arguing this is not a programming question, and he might have a point. Trouble is: hard for me to make the programming point due to my lack of knowledge in the Driver department. This much I know: The Win32 API allows you to Register code to run when API routines get called. This is called "hook" in programmer lingo, and it's a concept I'm familiar with. The idea would be that you could somehow insert some code between the OS and the Driver Setup Routine to return "all great, go on" instead of `ERROR_NON_WINDOWS_NT_DRIVER`. But I've never done that at the System/Driver Level.

It is true that this is not a concrete programming question. Way to go for me to get there.

I posted this on stackoverflow because I deemed it too hard for superuser and off-Topic for serverfault. If you could suggest a better Forum that would also be helpful.

---

Hardware background: The Driver in question is for a 2005 vintage Hardware (Samsung X20 notebook) featuring an Intel 915GM/GMS, 910GML chipset. Not enjoying Hardware Support and falling back on some VGA Driver is obviously somewhat detrimental to the overall user experience.

(I excuse for undue capitalization in this post - this is due to [the new spell-checker in IE10 which I haven't managed to disable yet](https://superuser.com/q/439517/69392).)

Comment: I can't see in any way how this could be considered a programming question. This is at best a hardware support question, and is off-topic here (it's about how to get an inappropriate driver to install on an OS it's not designed to support, IMO. XP drivers, btw, are **not** NT drivers.) [SO is not a substitute for vendor customer support](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128579/172661), and the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) is pretty clear regarding what questions should (and should not) be asked here. Voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: @KenWhite - I was suspecting this was about to happen. You might consider that I'm a developer interested in how things work and have already been through the Intel Forums. The point I'd like to make is that there is an error code that happens as part of the Driver Installation, but I'm not knowledgeable about Driver Installation and OS Driver handling as that's not my field of Expertise. I know there are things like MS Detours and Win32 API hooks, so one might be able to trap the error using one of those. You might want to reconsider your assessment of this as off-Topic.

Comment: You might then provide information about how this is a programming question by editing the question to ask a programming question. :-) I explained my reasoning, and you've provided no information to change that in your comment.

Comment: @KenWhite - I updated my question, but I cannot hope to get more specific due to lack of knowledge in this domain. So if it gets closed that'll be okay; I realise there's relatively little traffic on the driver tags here on SO, and also that my question might just not have an answer. You wrote: "XP drivers, btw, are not NT drivers." Could you expand on that? [It seems there is Windows Driver Foundation, its precursor WDM, and earlier technologies.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT#Driver_models) How would an XP driver differ from an NT driver? Couldn't find a reference. - Michael